# Rails: How to get comment.all.count in models/user.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

Let's say each User has_many Comments through a polymorphic association. How could I define the total number of Comments (in the whole application, not just for a specific User) in the User model?

Here's what I've tried so far:

models/user.rb

```
  def total_comments
    @user = User.all
    @user.comments.build
    @user.comments.count
  end
```

But I get the error "undefined method 'up_votes' "

Comment: Why not `Comment.count` ??

Comment: @ArupRakshit Should've known it was embarrassingly simple.

Comment: That's RoR development in a nutshell :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your method as :-

```
def total_comments
  @total_comments = Comment.count
end
```